# Recover data after selecting: "Erase disk and install Linux Mint"

Tags: linux, data-recovery

I tried to install the Linux Mint by selecting the option  by option : "Erase disk and install Linux Mint" assuming that the installation will be on C drive (where windows was installed ) but the installation failed due to some unknown reason relating to hard drive.

I have lost the all the partition and when I am trying again to install Linux Mint it shows only 1 partition of 500 GB (my HDD).

I am not sure if the I have lost all the data but is it possible to recover it ?

Comment: 1st rule of disk data recovery: data is lost slower when your system is off. Turn off your system (if possible) to prevent overwrites.

Comment: That's true.... I went on doing n different things which may have made the situation worst

Comment: What exactly have you lost?

Comment: Personal files and photos which were saved on D and E drive

Comment: Ah right. With linux, a 'disk' referes to a collection of partitions. Windows is slightly more vague with the terminology, using it to describe partitions. My answer should be able to help you recover most of it, but unfortunately, due to the nature of modern filesystems, there is a good chance that some of your data has been lost. I hate to be this guy, but if you don't have backups, you should start keeping them. Disk failures, as well as mistaken overwrites, are unfortunately easy ways of losing data.

Answer (score 1):

If it hasn't overwritten too much data, you should be able to recover the partition with `testdisk`. It is realtively easy to use, with a terminal ui to help you through the process.

- Flash a usb with [GParted Live](https://gparted.sourceforge.io/livecd.php) and boot into it. GParted Live is a brilliant tool for when you mess up your disk configuration.
- Start testdisk in the console

  - Select 'Create'
  - Pick your disk from the list
  - Select your partition type (usually Intel for ≤ 2TB, Usually GPT for > 2TB).
  - Select 'Analyse'
  - Select 'Quick Search'
  - After it has completed, press enter to continue
  - This should give you a list of partitions on your disk, including your deleted one. If it doesn't, select 'Deeper Search'.
  - You should be able to select the partition and restore it from the `testdisk` menu now.

Comment: I used the Linux Mint installation disk to use the tesdrive but my harddisk is not visible in the list..   I will try the same connecting my HDD to a different system

Comment: Try with the live disk, it may have a more up to date version. Avoid booting directly into the system, as that will probably cause more data to be lost.